# About Add two numbers from Leetcode Algorithm part(asking for few lines explanation )

Tags: java, algorithm

You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

And I don't understand the (public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2))why it gives two names for this  I wonder. thanks

```
     /**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * public class ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     ListNode next;
     *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
     * }
     */
    class Solution {
        public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode p = l1, q = l2, curr = dummyHead;

        int carry = 0;
        while (p != null || q != null) {
            int x = (p != null) ? p.val : 0;
            int y = (q != null) ? q.val : 0;
            int sum = carry + x + y;
            carry = sum / 10;
            curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            curr = curr.next;
            if (p != null) p = p.next;
            if (q != null) q = q.next;
        }
        if (carry > 0) {
            curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
        }
        return dummyHead.next;
    }

    }

Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `why it gives two names`?

Comment: ListNode and addTwoNumbers These two names I don't understand:(

Comment: are you new to programming? If yes please study some basic programming book first before solving such questions.

Comment: Yes I am, didn't code that much, this year I have some course about coding. thanks

Comment: @DongmingGuo `ListNode` is a `type` (aka `class`) and the `addTwoNumbers` is the name of the function. The whole bit between `{}` is declaring a public function `addTwoNumbers` that returns a variable of type `ListNode` after accepting two variables of type `ListNode`

Comment: @DongmingGuo this behavior is typical for "strong typed" programming languages, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

Comment: Thanks, recently I have tried to build something based on the simple java. While yesterday I tried to figure this question out and I don't want to skip this just because I am new to this language. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
It appears that you need more time with the basic principles of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Solution {
    /**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * public class ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     ListNode next;
     *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
     * }
     */

        public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
            ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
            ListNode p = l1, q = l2, curr = dummyHead;

            int carry = 0;
            while (p != null || q != null) {
                int x = (p != null) ? p.val : 0;
                int y = (q != null) ? q.val : 0;
                int sum = carry + x + y;
                carry = sum / 10;
                curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
                curr = curr.next;
                if (p != null) p = p.next;
                if (q != null) q = q.next;
            }
            if (carry > 0) {
                curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
            }
            return dummyHead.next;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Solution solution = new Solution();

        ListNode l1 = new ListNode(2);
        ListNode nextl11 = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode nextl12 = new ListNode(3);
        l1.next = nextl11;
        nextl11.next = nextl12;



        ListNode l2 = new ListNode(5);
        ListNode nextl21 = new ListNode(6);
        ListNode nextl22 = new ListNode(4);
        l2.next = nextl21;
        nextl21.next = nextl22;
        System.out.println(solution.addTwoNumbers(l1, l2));
    }

    }




public class ListNode {
          int val;
          ListNode next;
          ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
          public String toString() {
              if (next != null)
              return "" + val + " " + next.toString();
              else
                  return "" + val + " ";

          }

}
```